# Electron js, principles of workflow

Tags: javascript, electron, event-loop, libuv

There are a lot info about application (node), and render(chromium) processes in Electron. About the communication between these processes via data marshalling through IPC and separated contexts.

But there is no info about event-loop.

So there is the question. How many event loops are used in Electron: several event-loops (one for each process: app, renders) and then how does libuv work with it?; or is there one event-loop which is shared between these processes?

Comment: There are the conversations about this question with Electron developers:
[1. First](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4862) 
[2. Second](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5172)